# Android app keeps crashing on launch with no good reason

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium-mobile

I've been trying to figure this out for days, to no avail. I'm developing a simple android app with Titanium that works perfectly fine on iOS. Yet, when I launch it on android, it never starts. Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tiki.signals" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <!-- TI_MANIFEST -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="Signals" android:name="SignalsApplication"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

        <activity android:name=".SignalsActivity"
            android:label="Signals" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
        android:name="ti.modules.titanium.facebook.FBActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    />

        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" />

        <service android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Here's the logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(   81): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.tiki.signals/.SignalsActivity} from pid 176
D/PermissionCache(   35): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (1163 us)
D/dalvikvm(   81): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 842K, 14% free 11108K/12807K, paused 106ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(   81): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.385MB for 1536016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(   81): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 13% free 12606K/14343K, paused 105ms
W/WindowManager(   81): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
I/ActivityManager(   81): Start proc com.tiki.signals for activity com.tiki.signals/.SignalsActivity: pid=457 uid=10040 gids={1015, 3003}
I/dalvikvm(  457): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   81): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2
D/dalvikvm(   81): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 13% free 12619K/14343K, paused 8ms+32ms
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/TiApplication(  457): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 243K, 4% free 9294K/9607K, paused 7ms+6ms
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/TiApplication(  457): (main) [682,682] Titanium 1.8.2 (2012/02/23 17:46 59b3a90)
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 5% free 9434K/9927K, paused 6ms+4ms
I/TiApplication(  457): (main) [254,936] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
D/dalvikvm(  457): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tiki.signals/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x412a1e60
D/dalvikvm(  457): Added shared lib /data/data/com.tiki.signals/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x412a1e60
D/dalvikvm(  457): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.tiki.signals/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x412a1e60, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(  457): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tiki.signals/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x412a1e60
I/TiRootActivity(  457): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
D/dalvikvm(  457): Added shared lib /data/data/com.tiki.signals/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x412a1e60
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
E/TiApplication(  457): (KrollRuntimeThread) [3551,3551] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@41334e08
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 349K, 5% free 9566K/10055K, paused 7ms+6ms
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 452K, 7% free 9534K/10183K, paused 84ms
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/TiLocation(  457): (main) [2290,5841] preferredProvider property found [null]
D/TiLocation(  457): (main) [1,5842] accuracy property found [0]
E/TiLocationHelper(  457): (main) [31,5873] unable to register, provider is null
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 7% free 9571K/10183K, paused 61ms
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm-heap(  457): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.878MB for 1536016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(  457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 11070K/11719K, paused 8ms+5ms
I/TiRootActivity(  457): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.tiki.signals.SignalsActivity@412aba88
V/PhoneStatusBar(  134): setLightsOn(true)
I/Process (   81): Sending signal. PID: 457 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
W/InputManagerService(   81): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41434cb8 (uid=10013 pid=176)
I/dalvikvm(  457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/gralloc_goldfish(  457): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/ActivityManager(   81): Displayed com.tiki.signals/.SignalsActivity: +9s553ms
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   81): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
D/ExchangeService(  355): Received deviceId from Email app: androidc259148960
D/ExchangeService(  355): Reconciling accounts...
D/dalvikvm(   81): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1712K, 23% free 11125K/14343K, paused 7ms+11ms
W/ThrottleService(   81): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
W/TiAnalyticsSvc(  457): (Thread-65) [23787,23787] Analytics Service Started
I/TiAnalyticsSvc(  457): (Thread-65) [152,23939] Sending 2 analytics events.
W/TiAnalyticsSvc(  457): (Thread-65) [1072,25011] Stopping Analytics Service
```

Here's my tiapp.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="ti.android.runtime">v8</property>
    <property name="ti.android.threadstacksize" type="int">132768</property>
    <property name="ti.android.fastdev" type="bool">false</property>
    <sdk-version>1.8.2</sdk-version>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <id>com.tiki.signals</id>
    <name>Signals</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>Michael</publisher>
    <url>http://</url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>2012 by meilers</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>49aefe11-b922-4f04-bffd-887ed59cb5d3</guid>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <modules/>
</ti:app>
```

What is happening here? I don't see any error in logcat. The VM is just shutting down, with no reason. Please help!

Comment: Looks like you have org/apache/commons/codec classes defined twice.  Have you looked int this?  Perhaps these are already included in Android.

Comment: It's almost like you are installing the package over and over again, but not actually running it, which might be a problem with your development machine setup.  Can you disconnect the USB cable and start the activity from its launcher icon?  If it fails, then reconnect the cable, run logcat, and give us the output from the last startup attempt.  Alterantively, see if you can build and run one of the SDK samples that has nothing to do with Titanium, and assuming that works, then one of the Titanium samples with no personal changes.

Comment: @chris: I'm not connected to any android device. I edited my post to show you the last attempt with logcat.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were running on the emulator.  Looks like you are getting an application not responding timeout error?  can you enable timestamps on logcat?  Do you get any error dialogs popping up on the emulator?  What happens with android sdk samples and/or Ti samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One item comes to mind just looking at the logcat... Not enough memory. You'll see memory free dip to 3% YIKES!. Usually try to keep 10% free or OS may go into a paging fit and possible time out some features.

Disable some features in the app and watch the memory under the emulator.
Best recommendation install the app onto actual phone, though the emulator is supposed to give close tor real world results. Which I dont count on emulating any hardware device well.

Here's some code to dump memory usage.  You need to find out what your target class is.
Older phones have as little as 16MB newer ones 48MB before the OS starts picking on your app. Put code in Oncreate.

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
 Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:>>>>>" + Long.toString(maxMemory));   //max available memory to use

 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
 Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:>>>>" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));  //max available you should use to keep from getting bumped off

 printl("PGM MEM FREE MB", GetInternalMemAvail());
 printl("INTERNAL STORAGE FREE MEMORY BYTES",getmem());
 printl("INTERNAL TOTAL MEMORY BYTES",TotalMemory());
 printl("SD MEM FREE MB",GetSDMemAvail());
 printl("SD MEM GB",getAvailableSpaceInGB());

 private static void printl(String printstring,long x)
 {
  String temp;
  temp=String.format(" %d",x);
  Log.e(printstring,temp);  
 }
```